# How can I add velocity to the standard CharacterController?

Tags: unity

I have FPS controller from standard asset.  After a long trial and error I figured that `CharacterController` doesn't respond to `AddForce`.

So, I have this trigger in the scene which I would like to throw FPS controller upwards.

Now, I know that I need to replace `AddForce` with adding velocity to the player. How to do that?

I need to use FPS controller component for velocity and add `Vector3.up`.
So, every game object *other* which will enter the trigger, will get upwards velocity.

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    other.attachedRigidbody.AddForce(Vector3.up * 100, ForceMode.Impulse);      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't have an understanding of Object-Oriented programming, AddForce is a method from Rigidbody class, FPSController is another class, so it is not a shared method. What both classes have, is a GetComponent function, which returns to you a component (base class of both Rigidbody and FPSController) of the type you provide. So what you can do is use GetComponent to get the Rigidbody's component of the object you collide with, and then call AddForce.

Other problem you have, is that you are calling other.AddForce, taking as granted that the objects you collide with will have Rigidbody, that is why you first check either the other object's tag or layer, to see if it is on the category of objects of a cerain type.

Example:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider obj)
{
    if(obj.CompareTag("DesiredTag"))
    {
        Rigidbody r = obj.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        if(r != null) r.Addforce(Vector3.up);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I understand, but I want to replace rigidbody and AddForce with velocity. So, I would like to add velocity to the object/collider.

Comment: if you want to alter the velocity, which is also not recommended on the documentation, since you are cancelling previous forces applied on that frame, you still need the rigidbody, since velocity is a property of the Rigidbody.

Comment: If you want to alter velocity, you can still do it via `Rigidbody.AddForce()` using the `ForceMode.VelocityChange` mode; it is integrated in the physics engine, and it's much nicer than hardsetting a different value via code. But, as @LinkWindcrafter said, you alter the GameObject's velocity (your object), not the Collider's (a __part__, a __component__ of your object). If your GameObject has a RigidBody component, altering the RigidBody component's velocity is equivalent to altering the GameObject's.

Comment: Thank youz. Is it possible to change GameObject's velocity without Rigidbody component. So ,using only Character controller component ?

Comment: No, it is no posible. As I said previously, velocity is a property from the rigidbody only. If you want, you could implement your own velocity in a custom script (i could update my answer to show you an approximate approach). Though the solution of storing the Rigidbody from the FPSController is more than enough, there is no need to reinvent the wheel.